# Posting a base64Image

Tags: java, spring, image, base64

I'm trying to post two string and a *.jpg (Base64) file to a Spring servlet, and i am getting a http 400 error, i understand that this error is due to the `@RequestParam` being set to `required = true`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "blurred-url/start", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> start(@RequestParam(value = "base64Image", required = true) final String base64Image,
                                        @RequestParam(value = "transactionId", required = true) final String transactionId,
                                        @RequestParam(value = "counterSignature", required = true) final String counterSignature)
```

I am using the following code to encode the image File to Base64 ( harded coded for now)

```
public static String getImage(){

        File file = new File("c://nota.jpg");

        byte[] imageByteArray = null;
        String imageDataString = null;

        try {            

            FileInputStream imageInFile = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte imageData[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];

            imageInFile.read(imageData);
            imageDataString = encodeImage(imageData);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return imageDataString;

    }

     /**
     * Encodes the byte array into base64 string
     *
     * @param imageByteArray - byte array
     * @return String a {@link java.lang.String}
     */
    public static String encodeImage(byte[] imageByteArray) {
        return Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(imageByteArray);
    }
```

I already tried with many different approaches using Apache HttpClient, right now i am using `MultipartEntityBuilder`, but still can't seem to get it working, code below

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

        try {
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/server-name/" +
                    "blurred-url.action");

            StringBody base64Image = new StringBody("123", ContentType.TEXT_HTML);
            StringBody transactionId = new StringBody(jsonObj.get("signature").getAsString(), ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
            StringBody signature = new StringBody(jsonObj.get("signature").getAsString(), ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);

            HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                    .addPart("base64Image", base64Image)
                    .addPart("counterSignature", signature)
                    .addPart("transactionId", transactionId)
                    .build();

            httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            try {

                if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){

                    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

                    if (resEntity != null) {
                        System.out.println("Response content length: " + resEntity.getContentLength());
                    }
                    EntityUtils.consume(resEntity);

                    JsonObject jsPost = getJsonObjectFromStream(resEntity.getContent());

                    System.out.println("success: "+jsPost.get("success"));

                }else{
                    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

                    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                    IOUtils.copy(resEntity.getContent(), writer,Charset.defaultCharset());

                    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
                    System.err.println(writer.toString());
                }
            } finally {
                response.close();
            }
        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
```

I believe there is something wrong with the size of the file, and i think that because if i just change the image encoded string to a shorter string like "123" the request passes, right now i am working with 400 KB images, any ideas ?

Comment: if you are running your code on tomcat add this  maxPostSize="0" to the http connector in server.xml

Comment: i am using tomcat7:run maven plugin, i am trying to find out how to set maven.tomcat.maxPostSize = 0

Comment: It appeared to have worked, the request is passing, i used `<configuration><maxPostSize>0</maxPostSize></configuration>`